# c++ global object

Tags: c++

I wanna create a global object in cpp program, how do I do that?
Is this right?
in "global_obj.h"

```
#include "class.h"
Class obj;
```

in "main.cpp"

```
extern Class obj;
```

Comment: Your one answer is absolutely correct. The `extern` declaration belongs in the header file. The non-`extern` definition belongs in exactly one `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We declare our globals as `extern` in a header file, in your case: global_obj.h, and the actual global variable in a source file: global_obj.cpp. In separate source files we `#include "global_obj.h"` to have access to them.

It should look like this:

global_obj.cpp

```
Class obj;
```

global_obj.h

```
extern Class obj;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "global_obj.h"
```

Comment: How do I access that object in other source.cpp?