# c++ global object declaration

Tags: c++, object, declaration

At the moment I am trying to declare a global object in c++ as follows:

in globals.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Class.h"

extern Class *obj;
```

then in a separate file called globals.cpp I have

```
#include "globals.h"
Class *obj;
```

And then in main.cpp I have

```
#include "globals.h"
```

But the compiler throws this error at me

```
in globals.h: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

I don't understand this since this post: [c++ global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918010/c-global-object) explains that this is the way it's done.

Comment: It is. Something's wrong that we can't see. Make a testcase.

Comment: does class.h include globals.h?

Comment: 'Class' is just a placeholder for the class name. 'Class.h' includes 'globals.h' and when this is removed the program compiles but throws an access exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `class.h` including `globals.h`. You say that if you do this, the program compiles but throws an access violation. Then there's an error in the logic, that's a different issue.

Fix compiler errors first. The access violation is probably because you didn't initialize the global correctly - i.e. as you have it, it's just a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: It works if I place everything inside Main.cpp though. If I remove 'globals.h' from 'class.h' and keep everything else the same, I now get the error 'in Main.cpp: error C2065: 'Obj' : undeclared identifier.

Comment: It was indeed an improper initialization. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`C2143` usually means you the compiler is not finding the definition/declaration of `class Class` before the variable declaration.

One way you can have it is that you have probably missed the semicolon at the end of the class definition in `class.h`.

In `class.h`

You have

```
class Class
{
    ....
}
```

You have forgotten the semicolon above.

Change to

```
class Class
{
    ....
} ;
```

If this is not the case, is there any other reason the definition of class Class is not found in class.h - is it inside #ifdefs or something?

Try compiling with /P and then open `main.i` in an editor and check if you see the declaration of `class Class` before the `extern` statement.

Comment: Thank you, it was not necessary to follow these steps as Luchian Grigore solved the problem.