# How to fix duplicated functions in object files?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, g++, project-structure

I'm building a program just to increase my OOP skills. This is my project structure:

```
Project
 -.vscode
 -build
 -includes
   - ContactInfo.h
   - Customer.h
   - Owner.h
   - PersonalInfo.h
   - User.h
 -src
   - ContactInfo.cpp
   - Customer.cpp
   - Owner.cpp
   - PersonalInfo.cpp
   - User.cpp
   - wrapper.h
   - wrapper.cpp
   - main.cpp
 - CMakeLists.txt
```

The problem is when I type command `make` in cmd at build file path, I get this following error:

```
duplicate symbol '_key' in:
    CMakeFiles/make_test_project.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/make_test_project.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_customers' in:
    CMakeFiles/make_test_project.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/make_test_project.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [make_test_project] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/make_test_project.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can guess what's happening here, I'm basically including `wrapper.h` file in both `main.cpp` and `wrapper.cpp` files but I don't know how to fix it. I also want to keep my project structure this way. So is there any way to fix this error ?

This is my `wrapper.h` file:

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

#include "../includes/Customer.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

char key;

void printUI();
void RunApplication();
PersonalInfo CreatePersonalInfo(std::string &, std::string &, int & );
ContactInfo CreateContactInfo(std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, int&);
void DisplayAllCustomers();
void AddCustomerToList(Customer &);
Customer CreateCustomer(PersonalInfo &, ContactInfo &);

std::vector<Customer> customers;

#endif
```

This is my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "wrapper.h"

int main()
{   
    RunApplication();
}
```

This below is my `CMakeLists.txt`  file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(cmake_test_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(make_test_project src/main.cpp src/wrapper.cpp src/ContactInfo.cpp src/PersonalInfo.cpp src/Customer.cpp src/User.cpp)
```

Note: I'm not gonna share `wrapper.cpp` file since it's a file composed of almost 120 lines but I can give you the information that  I also included `wrapper.h` file in `wrapper.cpp` file.

Please feel free to ask more information, Thanks.

Comment: See [c++ global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918010/c-global-object) to solve at least one issue, but the error also mentions undefined reference, which means linker cannot see the definition of `printUI` in any source file.

Comment: That was the previous error I'd been dealing. I didn't mean to ask that error, I copied the wrong error. I put the correct one now though.

Comment: change to `extern char key;` and add a `char key;`  to One .cpp file.

Comment: @Ali Then see the linked question. You may not put definition of global variable in header file, except when it would be `inline` (doable since C++17). You should move those variables to a .cpp file and only `extern` them in header to make them accessible in other .cpp files.

Comment: @Surt Thanks, that fixed the problem with the key. Now there is only one duplicate left. Can you check that too ?

Comment: Do the same for `customers`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen by the way, should I seperate ```extern```  ```.h```files and normal ```.h files ``` into 2 separate ```.h```files ?

Comment: The first thing would be to not use global objects. If you do need them, it's just a matter of your convention where to place the externs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wrapper.h

```
extern char key;

void printUI();
void RunApplication();
PersonalInfo CreatePersonalInfo(std::string &, std::string &, int & );
ContactInfo CreateContactInfo(std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, int&);
void DisplayAllCustomers();
void AddCustomerToList(Customer &);
Customer CreateCustomer(PersonalInfo &, ContactInfo &);

extern std::vector<Customer> customers;
```

And declare both in One and only one .cpp file.

If you got C++17 you can just exchange the extern with `inline` and your done.

Comment: Thanks! I did the samething to the ```customers``` and everything fixed.